# Xamarin Android how to handle Twilio chat sending message fail event

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I implement the below code for send messages using Twilio but I'm not getting any error when messages fail to deliver due to internet issues.

```
Com.Twilio.Chat.Message.Options options = Com.Twilio.Chat.Message.InvokeOptions().WithAttributes(jSON);
TwillioChatHelper.Instance.listOfChannel[position].Messages.SendMessage(options, new ChatMessageCallbackListner());

internal class ChatMessageCallbackListner : CallbackListener<Message>
{
    public override void OnSuccess(Message result)
    {

    }
    public override void OnError(ErrorInfo errorInfo)
    {
       base.OnError(errorInfo);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about this. Can I recommend you open an issue on the [Xamarin bindings repo](https://github.com/twilio/TwilioChatXamarinBindings) where the team responsible keeps an eye on things?

Comment: okay, I will create new issue in your recommendation thanks.